# Manual citation formatting

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing, harvard-style

First off: I don't want to use bibtex for this; I want to typeset my bibliography myself.

Looking at the `source2e.pdf` document I found out about redefining `\@cite` and `\@biblabel`, and got my citation style pretty much set up with this.

The problem which remains now is this: I'd like to allow for two different ways of citing a person. (This seems to be called “harvard style”.) One would be in the body of the text:

> … as John Doe (1900) demonstrated …

while the other one would be parenthesized:

> … has already been demonstrated (John Doe 1900).

Now my problem is the different handling of the year, which has to be parenthesized in one form but not in the other. Of course, I'd need two different commands for the different citations. But so far, every attempt at splitting up the citation label has failed, at least if I want to also use `hyperref`. Without that package, the following seems to satisfy my requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{ ({#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi})}
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\def\@cite@ofmt#1{\edef\my@tmp{#1}\expandafter\my@split\my@tmp}
\def\my@split#1(#2){\hbox{#1#2}}
\def\my@tcite#1#2{{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
\def\my@tsplit#1(#2){\hbox{#1(#2)}}
\newcommand\tcite[1]{{\let\@cite\my@tcite\let\my@split\my@tsplit\cite{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\ldots as \tcite{JohnDoe} demonstrated \ldots\par
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[John Doe (1900)]{JohnDoe}
John Doe, The famous book, 1900.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

But with `hyperref` enabled, I get this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
```

Looking at the source code of `hyperref.sty`, I see that it does attempt to support compatibility with the `harvard` package. So I adjusted my example to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\ldots as \citeasnoun{JohnDoe} demonstrated \ldots\par
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\harvarditem{John Doe}{1900}{JohnDoe}
John Doe, The famous book, 1900.\par
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

But I keep getting

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

no matter how many times I process the document. And I don't get any hyperlinks.

**How can I get harvard style citations with a manually set bibliography and with working hyperlinks for my citations?**

I'm using texlive 2013, which includes `hyperref.sty` v6.83m from 2012/11/06 and `harvard.sty` version 2.0.5 apparently from 1994.

Comment: Load `harvard` after `hyperref`. But you won't get hyperlinks.

Comment: @egreg - Better yet, don't load `harvard` at all; instead, load both `natbib` and `har2nat`. Using these two packages enables the hyperlinking of the citation callouts to the corresponding entries in the bibliography, while preserving the ability to use `harvard`-based macros such as `\citeasnoun` and `\harvarditem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on your already very thorough answer:

To achieve full inter-operability between citation commands and the `hyperref` package, it's advisable to load the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages instead of the `harvard` package. (If you load `natbib` and `har2nat`, you should *not* load the `harvard` package.)

In the example below, note that `\harvarditem` and `\citeasnoun` are `harvard`-based macros that are "translated" transparently by the `har2nat` package into instructions that are understood by `natbib`. The macro `\cite`, which is also available in "Basic LaTeX" (i.e., without any citation-management packages being loaded), is modified by `natbib` to be usable for authoryear-style citations. Finally, `\citet`, `\citep`, `\citealt`, `\citealp`, and `\citeauthor` are macros provided directly by the `natbib` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\ldots\ has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.

\ldots\ as \citeasnoun{JohnDoe} has demonstrated \ldots

\citet{JohnDoe}; \citealt{JohnDoe}

\citep{JohnDoe}; \citealp{JohnDoe}

\citeauthor{JohnDoe}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\harvarditem{Doe}{1900}{JohnDoe}
John Doe, {\em The Famous Book}, Forest Glen: The Buck Press. 1900.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're building the bibliography entirely by hand anyway, there's no real reason to take a detour via `\harvarditem{}{}{}...` instructions and have them be "translated" into `natbib`-equivalent directives. Instead, just use the `natbib`-based syntax directly. (Doing so will also let you skip having to load `har2nat`). The preceding code would then look like this -- note the use of `\bibitem` instead of `\harvarditem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\ldots\ has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.

\ldots\ as \citeauthor{JohnDoe} has demonstrated \ldots

\citet{JohnDoe}; \citealt{JohnDoe}

\citep{JohnDoe}; \citealp{JohnDoe}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Doe(1900)]{JohnDoe}
John Doe, {\em The Famous Book}, Forest Glen: The Buck Press. 1900.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the sources, I noticed that while `\cite` and `\citeasnoun` come from `har2nat`, the support for `\harvarditem` appears to be coded directly into `natbib`. `har2nat.sty` is really small. Nevertheless, I do prefer the `\bibitem` style you used in your example, so I'll stick with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

## Make harvard and hyperref cooperate

`harvard` will load `html` (if it exists) which in turn will load `hyperref` when using `pdflatex`. So `hyperref` is loaded before `harvard` even if you use these packaes in a different order. Therefore `hyperred` cannot define `\harvardcite` directly, since otherwise the `\newcommand` in `harvard` would complain. Instead, `hyperref` tries to redefine that macro in its `\AtBeginDocument` hook. But that is too late: that hook is executed *after* the `jobname.aux` file got read in, and it's that aux file which contains the `\harvardcite` calls where this is needed. So the version from `hyperref` is never called.

So my workaround at the moment is to unconditionally define `\harvardcite` the way `hyperref` defines it, but do so before the `jobname.aux` file is read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{harvard}

\makeatletter
\gdef\harvardcite#1#2#3#4{%
  \global\@namedef{HAR@fn@#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}%
  \global\@namedef{HAR@an@#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#3}}%
  \global\@namedef{HAR@yr@#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#4}}%
  \global\@namedef{HAR@df@#1}{\csname HAR@fn@#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\ldots as \citeasnoun{JohnDoe} demonstrated \ldots\par
\ldots has already been demonstrated \cite{JohnDoe}.\par
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\harvarditem{John Doe}{1900}{JohnDoe}
John Doe, The famous book, 1900.\par
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

In this toy example I still get warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{cite.JohnDoe} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

But in the real document where I actually need this, things work out fine. Not sure what's going on here, but I'm happy as long as things work where I really need them. And even the toy looks sane enough, despite the warnings.

Comment: In order to get optimal inter-operability with `hyperref`, it's actually better to load both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages instead of the `harvard` package.

Comment: @Mico: That sounds like a good suggestion, and seems to work out of the box. Would you care to post that as an answer in its own right?

Comment: You may want to send a link to this posting to the maintainer(s) of the `hyperref` package to alert him/them to the problem that that package's harvard-related macros aren't executed at the correct time.