# How to create new citation style that is not included in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm making a template for article submission to Latin America Antiquity and noticed that they use a [citation style](https://documents.saa.org/container/docs/default-source/doc-publications/style-guide/saa-style-guide_english_updated_2021_final08023c15928949dabd02faafb269fb1c.pdf?sfvrsn=c1f41c1b_2) that is not included in [Biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). How can i create a style in Biblatex (and how can i upload it to be used by others)?

Comment: Before you start writing a `biblatex` style for that journal, double-check (possibly with the editor if there are no positive statements about this in the submission guidelines) that they accept LaTeX submissions and if they do so, double check that they can accept `biblatex` bibliographies. Many journals that accept LaTeX submissions want standard `thebibliography`/BibTeX-based bibliographies. The workflow for `biblatex` bibliographies is significantly different.

Comment: That all said, depending on how different the required style is from the output of one of the standard styles, you may be able to get away with "light" modifications such as the ones discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. Or you may have to get more serious as shown for example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554623/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542604/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542415/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560167/35864,

Comment: In the [editorial policy](https://documents.saa.org/container/docs/default-source/doc-publications/style-guide/saa-style-guide_english_updated_2021_final08023c15928949dabd02faafb269fb1c.pdf?sfvrsn=c1f41c1b_2), page 12, they say that they accept LaTeX source files, but they didnt have provided any templates neither have said which citation style they prefer. Will check with then if Biblatex can be used, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I looked at https://www.saa.org/publications/latin-american-antiquity.
- The [Style Guide](https://documents.saa.org/container/docs/default-source/doc-publications/style-guide/saa-style-guide_english_updated_2021_final08023c15928949dabd02faafb269fb1c.pdf?sfvrsn=c1f41c1b_2) states the following.

> To alleviate software incompatibilities and related digital problems,
> authors using automated utilities such as linked footnotes and
> endnotes in MS Word or a bibliographic compiler (e.g., EndNote) **must**
> **convert the output to plain text before uploading**. Note that authors
> **may also upload LaTeX source files to EM for peer review**.
>
> [...]
>
> When formatting references cited prior to submitting a manuscript, **authors should not
> attempt to duplicate how references look after they are typeset**. Instead, authors should
> format them as follows. Entries should be flush left with an extra space between each
> entry. Authorship goes on the first line, followed by a hard return. The second line would
> be [tab] date [tab] title, etc. The title and remaining text of the reference should be
> allowed to flow without a hanging indentation as is seen in the typeset version.
>
> [...]
>
> If a bibliographic compiler (e.g., EndNote) has been used, authors are required to convert
> the output to plain text before submitting/uploading manuscripts.

- If I were you, I would just create the bibliography [manually](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/BibMan.html) (or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292101), or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178618)) in this case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]